# Split a column list into columns

Tags: r, list, data.table

Suppose I have a DT as -

```
id         values          valid_types   
 1            2|3             100|200  
 2              4                 200  
 3            2|1             500|100
```

The `valid_types` tells me what are the valid types I need. There are 4 total types(100, 200, 500, 2000). An entry specifies their valid types and their corresponding values with `|` separated character values.

I want to transform this to a DT which has the types as columns and their corresponding values.

Expected:

```
id   100   200  500
 1     2     3   NA
 2    NA     4   NA
 3     1    NA    2
```

I thought I could take both the columns and split them on `|` which would give me two lists. I would then combine them by setting the keys as names of the types list and then convert the final list to a DT.

But the idea I came up with is very convoluted and not really working.

Is there a better/easier way to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another `data.table` approach:

```
dcast(
  DT[, lapply(.SD, function(x) strsplit(x, "\\|")[[1L]]), by = id], 
  id ~ valid_types, value.var = "values"
)
```

Comment: Ah. I was doing this and you solved it before I could. Thanks. This is what I want

Comment: What if my key id is a composite of 2 cols -> `id,date`. I can change the by cluase but how do i do the same for `id~valid_types` ?

Comment: @leoOrion `id + date ~ valid_types`

Answer (score 2):

Using `tidyr` library you can use `separate_rows` with `pivot_wider` :

```
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  separate_rows(values, valid_types, sep = '\\|', convert = TRUE) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = valid_types, values_from = values)

#     id `100` `200` `500`
#  <int> <int> <int> <int>
#1     1     2     3    NA
#2     2    NA     4    NA
#3     3     1    NA     2
```

---

A `data.table` way would be :

```
library(data.table)
library(splitstackshape)

setDT(df)
dcast(cSplit(df, c('values', 'valid_types'), sep = '|', direction = 'long'), 
                 id~valid_types, value.var = 'values')
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without `tidyr` ?

Comment: Thanks. But I was trying to achieve this with minimal packages. Hence going with the other answer although this solves it as well.